# Ubuntu error — cannot import name 'gcd' from 'fractions'

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu to learn basic bioinformatics. I just downloaded multiqc using conda, but when I want to run multiqc, it returns:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCNzS.jpg)

I am very naive and don't know how to solve this problem. ANY help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think gcd was moved to the math pack in 3.9. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html

> Changed in version 3.9: The math.gcd() function is now used to normalize the numerator and denominator. math.gcd() always return a int type. Previously, the GCD type depended on numerator and denominator.

I suggest you create a virtual environment with 3.8 and try that. There are tons of tutorials on how to do this.

Comment: @HamidKainGaikani Welcome, If this post answer your question, please do not forget to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew said, Python 3.8 can be installed virtually. However, I just asked Conda to reinstall the older version of python (3.8), and now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens when you have an outdated version of the `networkx` package, which is a MultiQC dependency. You can fix it by updating this package:

```sh
conda install networkx=2.5.1
```

The next release of MultiQC (v1.11) will specify that at least this version of `networkx` is required, to ensure Python 3.9 compatability.

GitHub issue where this was tracked down: https://github.com/ewels/MultiQC/issues/1413